# How to write conditional expression using Gpath in GSP page

Tags: grails, gsp, gpath

I want to display the attachments whose type may be 1 or 4 or 5

`${attachments} has got attachments with the attributes name, type`

**EDIT:**

```
<g:findAll in="${attachments}" expr="it.type==1 || it.type==4 ||  it.type==5">
       <p>File: ${it.name}, ${it.type}</p>
    </g:findAll>
```

I was trying the above method, it didn't work, How to do this.

Answer (score 0):

```
<g:each in="${attachments.findAll{[1,4,5].contains(it.type)}}">
    <p>File: ${it.name}, ${it.type}</p>
</g:each>
```